# mStartTime cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, variables

I have written the following code:

```
package com.shadow.handler;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServiceClick extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
    }
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               final long start = mStartTime;
               long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
               int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
               int minutes = seconds / 60;
               seconds     = seconds % 60;

               if (seconds < 10) {
                   mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
               } else {
                   mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);            
               }

               mHandler.postAtTime(this,
                       start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
           }
        };

    public void startClicked(View view) {
        if (mStartTime == 0L) {
            mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    public void stopClicked(View view) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
mStartTime cannot be resolved to a variable
mHandler cannot be resolved
```

But I have already declared mStartTime and mHandler.

Comment: Where is the declaration of mStartTime or mHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared those variables. You need to declare them

```
Handler mHandler;
long mStartTime;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Also you need to remove

```
import android.R;
```

Should be

```
import com.shadow.handler.R;
```

Also i don't see where you initialized `mHandler`.